# How to loop download pdf in swift4 from array of url

Tags: alamofire, swift4, urlsession

i want to loop download pdf file from array of url from my server side and i want to make it run in background when user close the viewcontroller and open the main form, also in main form we can open the download viewcontroller again to see the progress of the download. i've already done it with Alamofire and using it as recursive(call itself again after download each file complete and using for-loop with popLast function to pop the url from array) But the problem is i can't track the request that in background and i can't check if the background request is already running or not. if we can't do it in alamofire, can the urlsession achieve what i want to do?

please kinda help. i really need all of your help, also i'm a beginner in IOS and in Stackoverflow, please forgive me if i'm wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I understand from your description that you need to sync all tasks. In your case, you can use **DispatchGroup**.  it allows for aggregate synchronization of work. You can use it to submit multiple different pdf URLs to download and track when they all complete by **group.notify** method.

Check the Sample code below:

```
func fetchPdfFiles(){
let group = DispatchGroup()
let urlList = ["Pdfurl1", "Pdfurl2", "Pdfurl3"]
// start your progressbar if you like
for str in urlList {
    group.enter()
    call_your_alamofire_Request(url: str, onCompletion: { (response) in
        do  {
            //save your pdf
            //Update progress bar
        } catch let error {
            print("Error:", error)
            //Handle error
        }
        group.leave()
    })
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("- all pdfs Download done")
    // Finally you need to do what ever if you like
    //Stop progressbar
 }
}
```